# Set video expiration with graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to set an expiration date & expiration type for videos on Facebook with PHP Graph SDK ([link to docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/video)). I always get `(#100) Invalid format for expiration param`. I've tried serveral date formats as ISO8601, timestamp like other dates and associative arrays to pass it as an object `$params['expiration']['time'] = 2018-02-04T23:57:00+0100`

Whats the correct way to set up this parameter?

```
$this->handle=new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'=>'xxx',
    'app_secret'=>'xxx',
    'default_graph_version'=>'v2.11',
    'default_access_token'=>$session
]);

// copied from print_r
$params = Array(
    [title] => videoname
    [name] => videoname
    [content_category] => ENTERTAINMENT
    [description] => some description text
    [embeddable] => 1
    [file_size] => 29089069
    [thumb] => Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile Object
        (
            [path:protected] => 7SQNP1186922FBPx2.jpg
            [maxLength:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
            [offset:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
            [stream:protected] => Resource id #164
        )

    [secret] => 
    [published] => 
    [no_story] => 
    [unpublished_content_type] => SCHEDULED
    [scheduled_publish_time] => 1517400300
    [expiration] => 2018-02-04T23:57:00+0100
    [expiration_type] => hide
)

$this->handle->post('/'.$fbpageID.'/videos',$params,$token);
```

I'm using graph v2.11 & latest SDK.

Comment: `expiration` is an object with two properties, `time` and `type`. You are sending a string value for `expiration` instead ...

Comment: I know, but how does this object look like in php? Do you have an example?

Comment: Have you tried supplying a simple associative array …?

Comment: yes like $params['expiration']['time'] = ... & $params['expiration']['type'], it didn't work. I should have noted this above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up as array was right, but with a few restrictions:

```
$params['published'] = true; // video must be already published
$params['expiration'] = [
    'time' => 1517400300, // as UTC timestamp
    'type' => 'expire_only' // required property
];
```